# vuejs plain object best practices

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to use plain javascript object in my vuejs app, but I don't find much examples on the web. There is any best practices ?
I added a models folder in my store folder with :

```
function Person (name) {
  this.name = name
  this.hi = function () {
    alert('Hi ! I\'m ' + this.name + '.')
  }
}
```

However when trying to use it in a component, like this

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click="test">Test</button>
</template>

<script>
  import Person from '@/store/models/Person.js'

  export default {
    name: 'PersoneComponent',
    methods: {
      test: function () {
        let myp = new Person('Bob')
        myp.hi()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have the following error :

```
error: 'Person' is defined but never used
```

There is something else to do ?

Comment: Is Person an object or a function?

Comment: you have to export it in the file, where it is defined and import it, where you want to use it.

Comment: you're right, I had to add export default function Person ...

Comment: @Robert Andrei in Javascript function (non arrow) are objects and can be instantiated via a constructor.

Comment: it works fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-pond-9cmcr